# Overflow 6 error on Long division in Excel VBA (possible bug)

Tags: vba, casting, overflow, variable-assignment, division

I'm getting a "**Run-time error code '6'**: *Overflow*" message on something that is trivial (imo).

Strange problem I'm experiencing here with the code below:

```
Sub StageSetup()
    Dim rLastDataRow As Range
    Dim lCount As Long: lCount = 0
    Dim lDelta As Long: lDelta = 0
    
1    With Worksheets("Analyzer")
2        Set rLastDataRow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown)
3        lCount = (rLastDataRow.Row - 2) / 10
4        lDelta = (rLastDataRow.Row - 2)
5        lCount = lDelta / 10
6    End With
End Sub
```

In debug mode, the problem is occurring on **line 5** above which is odd in that it is a simple long division.

Note:

1. I added **line 3** above after the fact just to see what happens when it is done in a single line.  That works, but I'd like it to work in the form shown in **line 5** as the future mods to this code will involve addition accumulations made to `lCount` before the division occurs.
2. `rLastDataRow.Row` when this happened was `2510` in value which so happen to be an evenly divisible value by `10` (stating the obvious).*

I could use a loop to simulate the division, but what's the point in doing that when a simple divide should suffice.

As can be seen, both `lCount` and `lDelta` are of Long type.  So, this should have been trivial as there shouldn't be any form of type conversion going on here.

I've tried casting the variable and literal utilizing `CLng` and also the `&` (as I've seen in some of the threads but thought that was only meant for non-decimal base representations) in various combinations to no avail.  I've also did some casting on **line 4** with no effect.

Does anyone have any clue what may be going on here?

Comment: I notice the issue seem to happen only when in Debug mode while stepping through the code.  (ODD).  I was trying to make sure the values are set correctly before adding more steps to the code.

Comment: Weird. Can't see anything in your code which would lead to that.

Comment: Try rewriting the offending code lines (no copy-paste), then comment out the old lines.

Comment: Runs fine for me.

Comment: Actually, I found out what is going on.  Somehow, the error only happens when I was in Debug mode.  Outside of debugging, it runs fine.  So, I just can't run debug with the division in place.  I think it's an Excel VBA bug.

Comment: What version of Excel are you running? I have used most versions for last 10 years without this occuring.

Comment: Excel for Mac version 16.42 (20101102) / VBA for Applications 7.1